# Как правильно изменять vuex state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Имеем store.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    "testObj": {
        item1: "item_1"
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_KEY(state) {
      state.testObj.item3 = "item_3"
    }
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
});
```

И два компонента:

1. TestComponent:

```
<template>
    <div>{{testObj}}</div>
</template>
<script>
    import { mapState } from "vuex"
    export default {
        name: "TestComponent",
        computed: {
            ...mapState({
                testObj: (state) => state.testObj
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

2. TestButton

```
<template>
   <input type="button" value="Click" @click="onClick">
</template>
<script>
    import { mapState } from "vuex"
    export default {
        name: "TestButton",
        computed: {
            ...mapState({
                testObj: (state) => state.testObj
            })
        },
        methods: {
            onClick: function() {
                this.$set(this.testObj, "item2", "item_2")
                this.$store.commit("SET_KEY")
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

При клике на кнопку я хочу реактивно изменять объект.
Я могу сделать это при помощи мутации `this.$store.commit("SET_KEY")` или же просто `this.$set(this.testObj, "item2", "item_2")`.

Верно ли я понимаю, что оба варианта допустимы? Есть ли между ними какая-то разница, кроме очевидной возможности "переиспользовать" мутацию.

Comment: Vue.set: _Добавление свойства к реактивному объекту, гарантируя, что новое свойство также будет реактивным и будет вызвано обновление представления._
Не очень понятно при чём тут vuex. Vuex следит за стейтом всего приложения. А сэт добавляет реактивное свойство во вьюху. Коммит в стейт обновит совйство для всего приложения и все компоненты приложения об этом узнают. А Vue.set работает в рамках одного компонента. Если не прав, прошу поправить, но документация говорит об этом.

Comment: _А Vue.set работает в рамках одного компонента_ В моем примере, при вызове `this.$set(this.testObj, "item2", "item_2")` в TestButton, изменения будут видны и в TestComponent

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        todos: [
            { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: true },
            { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
            { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: false },
            { text: "Build something awesome", done: false },
            { text: "Learn Vuex", done: false }
        ]
    },
    actions: {
        toggleTodo({ commit }, index) {
            commit('toggleTodo', index);
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        toggleTodo(state, index) {
            state.todos[index].done = !state.todos[index].done;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        todos: ({ todos }) => todos 
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    store,
    computed: {
        todos() {
            return this.$store.getters.todos;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggle(index) {
            this.$store.dispatch('toggleTodo', index);
        }
    }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.5.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h2>Todos с использованием Vuex:</h2>
    <ol>
        <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="toggle(index)" v-bind:checked="todo.done">

                <del v-if="todo.done">
                    {{ todo.text }}
                </del>
                <span v-else>
                    {{ todo.text }}
                </span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Vue API](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

> `Vue.set` - Добавление свойства к реактивному объекту, гарантируя, что
> новое свойство также будет реактивным и будет вызвано обновление
> представления. Это пригодится для добавления новых свойств к
> реактивным объектам, поскольку иначе `Vue` не может отследить эти
> изменения.

[Мутации Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/mutations.html)

> Единственным способом изменения состояния хранилища во Vuex являются мутации. Мутации во Vuex очень похожи на события: каждая мутация имеет строковый тип и функцию-обработчик. В этом обработчике и происходят, собственно, изменения состояния, переданного в функцию первым аргументом:

Вы должны понять, что первое всего-лишь обеспечивает создание реактивности свойств, а второе **синхронное изменение состояния Vuex**.

> Мутации следуют правилам реактивности Vue

Это значит, что в мутациях вы можете использовать `vue.set`(`$vm.set`) для добавления новых свойств, которые сразу же будут сделаны `vue` реактивными.

Не смотря на соблазн изменения данных из хранилища напрямую (в том числе и с помощью `vue.set`), не делайте этого, создатели `vuex` рекомендуют изменять состояние хранилища `vuex` только через мутации, потому ,что:

> привнесение асинхронности в мутации могло бы изрядно затруднить
> понимание логики программы. Например, если вызываются два метода, оба
> с асинхронными коллбэками, изменяющими состояние приложения — как
> предсказать, какой из коллбэков будет вызван первым? Именно поэтому
> концепции изменений и асинхронности рассматриваются по отдельности. Во
> Vuex мутации — это синхронные транзакции:

*- простым языком, чтобы избежать ошибок при расширении вашего приложения, для изменения данных хранилища `vuex` - используйте только мутации, потому, что они дают гарантию, что ваши данные будут изменены именно в той последовательности в которой вы будете инициировать их изменение*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. К сожалению, не понял вот это: _иначе ваше хранилище может стать неуправляемым, т.е. вы не сможете полагаться на его состояние, ввиду того, что вторая мутация может полагаться на результаты первой, которая может быть завершена после второй и так далее..._ Может быть есть какой-то пример, где все работает не так как должно?

Comment: пример подготовить не могу, дополнил ответ